# Calling an instance of a class inside another class as parameter input for different cpp files

Tags: c++, class, parameter-passing, header-files, instance-variables

I have two different classes: 
`

```
class displacement
{ vector_geometry d;
  //some functions and constructors 
};


class velocity
{
 vector_geometry d;
 //some functions and constructors
 velocity get_velocity(displacement d1, displacement d2, double time)
 {
   //calculate the average velocity by subtracting the displacements and 
   //dividing by time
}
```

displacement class is under displacement.cpp and velocity class is under velocity.cpp while vector_geometry `is a struct variable having x and y values`. It's a header file and included in both displacement.cpp and velocity,cpp

Whenever I try to build the project, I get an error saying `'displacement' has not been declared` in velocity get_velocity() function.

How do I use an instance of displacement as a parameter input in velocity.cpp? Or in general, How do I call any instance of a class inside another class? Am I getting the error because both are defined in defined in different cpp files? Should I then define a header displacement.h and include in velocity.cpp?

Comment: How are the classes supposed to know about each other? According to your description you didn't expose the declarations in header files (and have no `#include`s that would let them know about it either)

Comment: Declare both classes in their respective header files and then implement them in their cpp files. Then `#include "displacement.h` in `velocity.cpp`.

Comment: Okay. Doing that then.

Comment: @SombreroChicken Now I get more errors saying class 'displacement' has no member named x_val ;while x_val is a member of struct 'vector_geometry'. And I have included the header files appropriately I guess

Comment: x_val isn't a member of displacement, it is a member of displacement.d (or the vector_geometry struct, as you said)